# xCode - How best to clean up a project before completion

Tags: xcode

For each app I write, at the end of the project, despite walking through the code, I'm sure I've left in unused "stuff". Is there a good methodology to check whether variables and/or properties are unused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Xcode4 already locates unused variables while editing.

[image]

Then there is the static Analyzer that comes for free with Xcode.

Just use it by running it via ***Product***->***Analyze***

[image]

This will, among many other useful things locate and mark unused variable assignments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Till. Analyze found a potential leak, but I added a variable as a test, did not use it, but Analyze did not find it.  I then added a test property but Analyze did not find that either.

Comment: You are basically right, I was a bit unclear with my answer. Xcode locates unused local variables already while editing. The Analyzer however locates variable assignments that are never used.

Comment: Well, perhaps this is enough. Just because I name a variable, is it allocated memory right away, or not until its value is changed?